# Is 'source'-ing a vim file simlar to 'include' in other languages?

Tags: vimscript

When a vim file is `source`-ed is it like including the raw text of the file into the current script is it more like executing its contents and returning to the current file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different languages have different semantics for this, so I won't compare, but `source` in Vim is not exactly like either.

For one, Vim has script-local variables, which, in practice, mean file-local.

Take these examples:

`foo.vim` (practically lifted as-is from [`:h script-variable`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#script-variable)):

```
let s:counter = 0
function! StartCounting(incr)
    if a:incr
        function MyCounter()
            let s:counter = s:counter + 1
        endfunction
    else
        function MyCounter()
            let s:counter = s:counter - 1
        endfunction
    endif
endfunction
let b:bar=2
```

`bar.vim`:

```
let b:bar=1
source foo.vim
call StartCounting(1)
echo s:counter
echo b:bar
```

- If it were simply including the raw text, I'd expect to see `s:counter` have a non-zero value.
- If it were executing the contents and returning, I'd expect to see `b:bar` unchanged.

Instead, the output is:

```
Error detected while processing /tmp/bar.vim:
line    4:
E121: Undefined variable: s:counter
E15: Invalid expression: s:counter
2
```

So `b:bar` is changed by the sourced file, but a script-local variable defined in the sourced file is not directly accessible by the calling file.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like script scopes dynamically nest (like block scopes in Ruby or function scopes in ECMAScript, but dynamically, not lexically).

Comment: Is there a command similar to source that is equivalent to `include`, ie treat the file as though this text was inserted here? eg. say you had a some `set` commands used in some particular session, would there be a command like `#insert set_commands_1`

Comment: @vfclists `source` is enough for `set`, since `set` is either global (affects everything in the current Vim session) or buffer-local (affects only the current buffer if used as `setlocal`). It is not aware of scripts.